# silverlight dropdown menu

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

i'm trying to built a dropdown menu for a silverlight web application. it should look something like showed on the Screenshot. Does somebody has an idea how to implement this? I tried to use sl4popupmenu but the downloadable project doesn't work in expression blend or visual studio designer.

Regards,
float

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That shouldn't be too difficult to do. I'd suggest using [Blend](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc507094) and then just [edit the template](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/128884/290516.aspx) for the Combobox control. You can get [pretty crazy](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=40) with what you can do with templates.